# Android runtime permission GPS: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.pm.PackageManager android.content.Context.getPackageManager()'

Tags: java, android, cordova, android-permissions, runtime-permissions

I'm developing an Android project based on cordova, I have a class that use the GPS location, and I want to implement the new permission runtime.

I have followed the official documentation and the google project from GitHub, but I get the following error:

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.pm.PackageManager android.content.Context.getPackageManager()' on a null object reference

At this line:

> if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(GpsTrackingActivity.this,Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION))

Here is the code:

```
private boolean checkPermission(){
    int result = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);
    if (result == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){

        return true;

    } else {

        return false;

    }
}

private void requestPermission(){

    if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(GpsTrackingActivity.this,Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)){

        android.widget.Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"GPS permission allows us to access location data. Please allow in App Settings for additional functionality.", android.widget.Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    } else {

        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION},PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
    }
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String permissions[], @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE:
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {


                Log.i(TAG_DBG, "Permission Granted, Now you can access location data.");
            } else {


                Log.i(TAG_DBG, "Please request permission");
            }
            break;
    }
}

public void startTravel(String travelId, CarProperties car) {

    Log.i(TAG_DBG, "L'utilisateur � appuy� sur Start");
    //askForPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,LOCATION);

    if (checkPermission()) {


        Log.i(TAG_DBG," Permission already granted");
    } else {
        Log.i(TAG_DBG, "Please request permission");

    }
    if (!checkPermission()) {

        requestPermission();

    } else {

        Log.i(TAG_DBG," Permission already granted");
    }

    location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
    //fb:bb#105: minTime to 1/2s instead of 1s to increase the number of fixes calculating effiMiles
    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 500, 10, this);
    ...
    ...
    ...
}
```

What is I did wrong?

Comment: Why is `startTravel` making calls on the `LocationManager` that require permissions? Permission requests are asynchronous, so you don't know whether the request has been granted until you've received the `onRequestPermissionsResult` callback.

Comment: I have the same problem.  Ever figure out the problem?